# HTML listing of recordset, resulting from a join on two tables that relate one-many

Tags: html, t-sql, asp-classic

I have two tables, that relate via a one-to-many relationship i.e

```
tableOne  (1)----------(*) tableTwo
```

Given the basic schema below

```
tableOne {
    groupID int PK,
    groupTitle varchar
}
```

and

```
tableTwo {
    bidID int PK,
    groupID int FK
}
```

Consider the two tables yield the following record-set based on joining the tables on the `tableOne.groupID = tableTwo.groupID,`

```
tableOne.groupID  |  tableOne.groupTitle   | tableTwo.bidID  |  tableTwo.groupID
________________________________________________________________________________ 

         1        |  Physics Group         |      1          |      1 

         2        |  Chemistry Group       |      2          |      2

         2        |  Chemistry Group       |      3          |      2

         1        |  Physics Group         |      4          |      1
```

I would like to list such a record-set in an HTML table as follows:

```
tableOne.groupID  |  tableOne.groupTitle   | tableTwo.bidID  |  tableTwo.groupID
________________________________________________________________________________ 

         1        |  Physics Group         |      1          |      1 

                  |  Physics Group         |      4          |      1

         2        |  Chemistry Group       |      2          |      2

                  |  Chemistry Group       |      3          |      2
```

I'm interested in finding out if this can be done in SQL, or alternatively finding out ways of listing such a record-set in HTML using good standards.

The solution  that comes to mind is simply iterating through the record-set and leveraging a sentinel to list all records with the same `tableOne.groupID` grouped in a single row `<tr>` - and also listing `tableOne.groupID`s once as a unique identifier of that record-group. However I don't want to go down that path as I would like to avoid mixing code with HTML if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order the sql results using the `ORDER BY` clause.

So if you add

```
ORDER BY tableOne.groupID ASC, tableTwo.bidID ASC
```

in your query, you are half-way there.

Next step is to loop and print the recordset from your asp page, but also check if the last `groupID` is different than the current, in order to decide whether to show it or not..